# Can the Length of String array be changed in JAVA ?

Tags: java, arrays, string, memory-management

I thought that the String array length cannot be changed once we define the size.
But I am not sure why it is allowing me to change it here (for the piece of code)?

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //size =3
        String[] roleNameArray = { "a", "b", "c" }; 

        // I also tried with 
          //String[] roleNameArray = new String[3];
          //roleNameArray[0]="a";
          //roleNameArray[1]="b";
          //roleNameArray[2]="c";

        System.out.println(roleNameArray.length);

        roleNameArray = addMoreValues();

        // size changed to 4
        System.out.println(roleNameArray.length);
    }

    public static String[] addMoreValues() {
        final String[] roleNameArra = new String[4];
        roleNameArra[0] = "a";
        roleNameArra[1] = "b";
        roleNameArra[2] = "c";
        roleNameArra[3] = "d";
        return roleNameArra;
    }

}
```

> OUTPUT:- 3 4

Here the size=3 when we initialized the array "roleNameArray"
Then the size changes to 4 for "roleNameArra" being equated to "roleNameArray".

**Questions:-**

- The size of String array has been changed in this case?
- If not what happens in memory in this case of JAVA? (java
  version used 1.8)

Comment: You create an Array and reassign it

Comment: no, the size did not change, you simply have a completely new and unrelated array stored in the same variable.

Comment: If you don't know the size, use something like ArrayList<E> (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.But in this case, what happens to the old array, does it become a part of "Garbage collector" ?

Comment: Honestly, you claim to be an "Senior Java Development Engineer" and ask such very basic questions?

Comment: the only thing i am interested here is to learn irrespective of my postion.

Comment: Did you learn about upvotes already? :)

Comment: C-Otto : I did an upvote but it will not be reflected as I am new to stackoverflow. But I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method `addMoreValues` you are creating a new array, which has nothing to do with the old array. Only because you fill the variable named `roleNameArray` with a reference to the new array you see the updated length. If you just call `addMoreValues` without updating the local variable (so without `roleNameArray =`), the old and unchanged array will be used.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.But in this case, what happens to the old array, does it become a part of "Garbage collector" ?

Comment: The old array is still there, and if it is still stored in some variable (or anywhere else) it will not be collected by the GC. However, in your case, nothing can access the old array instance, so the GC will remove it from memory (at some later time).

Comment: Really, most probably the garbage collector will *not* collect the old array: it will not have an opportunity before the program terminates. The old array is *eligible* for collection, though. In a larger and more long-running program, whether it *will* be collected depends primarily on whether the space is needed for something else.

Comment: Thanks for your help really.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you created **new array instance**.

```
final String[] roleNameArra = new String[4];
```

And then you changed reference of old array to the new one (returned from function).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.But in this case, what happens to the old array, does it become a part of "Garbage collector" ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this ?

```
final String[] roleNameArra = new String[4];
```

You are not changing its size you are assigning it to a new one.

I recommend that you read more about java collections.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.But in this case, what happens to the old array, does it become a part of "Garbage collector" ?

Comment: No your old array is pointing to another array (on memory level). To make things simple for you: It is the same soul but you gave it a different body. 
I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't changed the length of the roleNameArray. In your method you created new array of size 4 and then returned the reference to it.

So now in roleNameArray you have array from your method, not from main.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.But in this case, what happens to the old array, does it become a part of "Garbage collector" ?

Comment: @GoravAgarwal exactly. there is no way to access that reference again. Unless you create the exact same array, in which case it will probably occupy the completely different place in memory